# Battery management - are there differences between distros?

Tags: linux, power-management

I have heard that Linux, in general, has poor notebook battery management: the battery lifetime is reduced significantly (I have noticed it on my MacBook 2.1 with Ferdora installed)

Are there any differences in power management between the distributions?

Answer (score 1):

It is [not recommended to run Linux an Apple Mac hardware](http://mjg59.livejournal.com/136710.html) because it is full of firmware obscurity and violations of specifications (like e.g. ACPI, EFI).

If your hardware is well supported under Linux (because the needed specifications are open/published enough and the vendor actually cares) then you get great battery/power management under every current major distribution.

For example, I observed optimal battery management with various Thinkpads, under various distributions. On other Intel based systems I observed better power-management (e.g. fan management) under Linux than under the pre-installed Windows Vista.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have currently Ideapad, do you know if it is supported as good as the mentioned Thinkpad?