# Is the power management on different linux distributions the same?

Tags: linux, power-management, distributions

I was wondering if the power management is the same across all linux distros? If no, what are the specific differences? I.e. can changing the distro possibly solve power management issues?

**Background**: I have a Lenovo X240 laptop (I thought this is a safe choice :)) and have several issue with the power management on linux Mint, which I cannot solve despite extensive research on stackoverflow sites and elsewhere. The issue are: The laptop lid does only *sometimes* lead to suspend to ram; *sometimes* the laptop freezes after wakeup from hibernation; the battery drain is really fast in suspend to ram..
Even if I describe quite specific problems in a specific configuration I believe this question has a broader scope.

There is [another question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/35481/battery-management-are-there-differences-between-distros) that asks for battery life across distros which is a different question although being close.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Power management is a matter of what software you have, not what distribution installed it, so on some level the answer is “yes”. It's always possible to re-create the same configuration on one distribution as on another distribution.

However, power management depends on the precise version of the software involved, especially the kernel. At any point in time, different distributions are likely to have different kernel versions, and to have applied different improvements and bug fixes. So in practice, especially if your hardware has only recently become supported, you might find that *one particular version of one distribution* works better than another version of the same distribution, or a version of another distribution.

It's also possible that different distributions have configured things in different ways. Sometimes hardware requires [proprietary blobs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_blob) to function optimally, and not all distributions install these by default or make it easy to install them explicitly. Distributions might also choose different defaults when there's a choice between, say, a solution that works for everyone but doesn't give optimal performance, and a solution that's optimal for 99% of users but crashes in 1% of the cases.

In many cases, for hardware issues, if you find configuration tips (e.g. some kernel options to apply) about one distribution, they're often applicable to other distributions. In particular, there's often a lot of information on the [Arch Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/) that's useful even for people who run other distributions. However, if your problem is that your drivers are too old, you may need to obtain more recent drivers.

Comment: Thanks for your comment! Is their any distro known to care about power management more than others? Or would be the rule of thumb the newer the better.

Answer (score 3):

Power management in Linux Mint is a function of systemd, and unfortunately the standard ACPI libraries don't communicate with the X240 very well.

I also own an X240 and after having ran in to similar issues I was able to solve them with help from this link: http://www.function.fr/advanced-linux-configuration-for-lenovo-thinkpad-x240/

You can also see in this guide that the battery life can be optimized for the X240 and the author of the guide claims over 20 hours with the appropriate adjustments.

Comment: so you suggest that it is not dependant on the distro but specific software packages that can be installed on any distro. btw: the link suggests to install tp_smapi but an error prevents the loading on my laptop, which is [described elsewhere too](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Tp_smapi#Supported_Laptops)